# Use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV'

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, fbsdk

After installing fbsdk on my React-Native app, I got this error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV'
```

This is in the file Pods > FBSDKCoreKit > FBSDKOrganicDeeplinkHelper.m

I got this even though I helped a friend doing exactly the same than me, and she didn't get it.
I tried to reinstall everything from scratch to check if the error didn't come from me not using the latest versions, but I still got this error.

A quick fix was to simply delete the case from the the `switch (device.userInterfaceIdiom)`, but I hope someone met this error before or has an idea of where it could come from.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error. You can fix this error by updating Xcode to the last version, currently 7.3.1.